# Need help understanding to create a mind mapping or flow charting app

Tags: ios, objective-c, quartz-2d

I want to create a mind mapping like app in iOS, but not sure how I am suppose to do that there are several questions in mind.

1. Should I use quartz2d?
2. How quartz2d will manage dynamic drawing placing, like if I want to move something then lines or connections will move accordingly.
3. How will flow chat expand, like how it will expand and user will keep getting the scrolling so drawing is not limited to fix area.

Comment: All those who down vote and vote for close tell me what should I ask . :(

Comment: Have you created mind map? If Yes, then could you please share the code with me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes
2. You have to keep track of lines and objects in a model, and update
   them appropriately when things are added/deleted/moved.
3. Subclass `UIScrollView` and override the `drawRect` method to draw
   the flow chart.  Change the `contentSize` to expand the
   drawing area as necessary, which enables scrolling at the same time.
   Also, you can enable the zoom feature if desired.