# Should I use Quartz2D to create a mind map interface?

Tags: ios, swift

Like this:

[image]

Can anybody give a hint? What are the APIs I need to use?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24819339/need-help-understanding-to-create-a-mind-mapping-or-flow-charting-app?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of an interface, I'd suggest looking at a few things there:

1) Being (i you're acquainted to it) the Cocoa / UIKit interface

I know it sounds like an obvious place to refer to, but tire's a load of info here on the apple site that helps.

2) Look at the "Core Animation" side of things i.e. CALayer, CAShapeLayer (for shapes like squares etc..) and CATextLayer (for text). They deal directly with proper layer "laying out" of shapes, layers, animations and text.

3) In terms of a simper one (like one that appears like a "filesystem" structure or if you're a windows user a "windows folder structure), then I'd suggest NSSourceView or etc...

The options are pretty pretty much all over the place so the way you want to do it is all there, how you want it don't is all there, etc...

Hav you got any examples of what you've seem and need more clarification on?

Comment: Anyway, pop me a question on internal chat and I'll try help more personally. I'v got a bit of time to help, so fire away :)

Comment: Thank u so much! I looked up NSSourceView, but I couldn't find it, and it's not a "filesystem" like structure, it's a different kind of mind map more like a database, while one piece of data can fall into several categories.

Comment: And UIKit is such a large thing I don't think I can look them all up, I wonder what is the view I should implement, like CollectionView or UIScrollView etc.

Comment: Maybe mostly I should use core animation to achieve all the work, like how to create a table view if Apple didn't offer a table view class.

Comment: How do I start a internal chat?

Comment: Did you draw it? If so can you guide me how to proceed..